# I want to set information to localstorage

Tags: javascript

```
playlist = [];
 //저장
 function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("playlist",JSON.stringify(playlist));
}
 // 리스트 생성
     $('td#btn-add-row').click(function() {
      // id 구하기
       var list_num = 1;
      for(var i=1; i <= 100; i++ )
      {
        if (  $('#basic tr td:nth-child(1)').hasClass(String(i)) == false )
        {
          list_num = i; break;
        }
      }
      // 추가
      const tbody = document.getElementById('my-tbody');
      const tr = document.createElement("tr");
      tr.id = list_num;

      const td1 = document.createElement("td");
      td1.className = list_num;
      td1.setAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer");

      const td2 = document.createElement("td");
      td2.innerText = "음악 "+list_num;

      const td3 = document.createElement("td");
      td3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='tb'>";

      const td4 = document.createElement("td");
      td4.innerHTML = "<input type='text'>";

      tbody.appendChild(tr);
      tr.appendChild(td1);
      tr.appendChild(td2);
      tr.appendChild(td3);
      tr.appendChild(td4);

      const data = {
         url:$("#my-tbody > tr:nth-child(" + list_num + ")> td> input").val(),
         name:$("#my-tbody > tr:nth-child(" + list_num + ")> td:nth-child(4)> input").val(),
         id:list_num
       }
       playlist.push(data);
       save();
    // 동적 테이블
     $("#basic").tableDnD();

      });
```

I wish that URL, name, id are stored in a local storage according to the id value of tr. However, this code produces strange results in `localstorage`. The problem is that the URL and name are not saved. What should I do?

[image: localStorage inspector screenshot]

Comment: So you are pushing the initial state, the values do not auto update your array. You have to code that. You are going to need to add onchange handlers and update your objects in your array.

Comment: What are you actually seeing in local storage? Just describing them as "strange" is not helpful -- very likely, it's doing exactly what it should, and it's _your expectations_ that are strange. Nobody can help you figure that out unless you share all the facts.

Comment: @epascarello I see a call to `save()` near the bottom of the click handler. OP isn't very clear, but I'm not sure yet that this is a case of expecting the storage content to be updated via mutation (although you are right: that would be a bad expectation).

Comment: @Tom Yeah, it saves the initial values. ;) Value reference does not magically update.

Comment: This would all be easier to understand if @woole would indent their code properly. Please help us out, here.

Answer (score 0):

The reference of a value does not magically keep on updating. So you need to add event listeners to keep updating it. So easiest thing to do is add event listeners to the inputs and update the array of objects.

Below is the basic idea. (note: StackOverflow blocks local storage so I commented it out.)

```js
// const playlist = localStorage.playlist ? JSON.parse(localStorage.playlist) : [];
const playlist = [];
const tableTbody = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  
    // either get the current value from localstorage or create new record
    playlist[i] = playlist[i] || {
      id: i,
      url: '',
      name: ''
    };
    const currentItem = playlist[i] 
 
    //create the table row
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.dataset.id = currentItem.id;
    
    // create the id cell
    const tdId = document.createElement("td");
    tdId.textContent = i + 1;
    
    // create the url cell
    const tdUrl = document.createElement("td");
    const inputUrl = document.createElement("input");
    inputUrl.type = "text";
    inputUrl.name = 'url';
    inputUrl.value = currentItem.url;
    tdUrl.append(inputUrl);

    // create the name cell
    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    const inputName = document.createElement("input");
    inputName.type = "text";
    inputName.name = 'name';
    inputName.value = currentItem.name;
    tdName.append(inputName);
    
    // add the cells to the row
    tr.append(tdId);
    tr.append(tdUrl);
    tr.append(tdName);
    
    // add the row to the table
    tableTbody.append(tr);
}

tableTbody.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  // see what triggered the input event
  const input = event.target;
  // find the row so we know what record to update
  const rowId = input.closest("tr").dataset("id");
  // what field to update
  const field = input.name;
  // update the record
  playlist[rowId][field] = input.value.trim();
  // update local storage
  // localStorage.playlist = JSON.stringify(playlist);
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th><th>url</th><th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```